# Distribution of objects into equally-sized groups

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many ways are there to distribute n distinct objects among g identical groups, where n mod g = 0 if all groups must contain the same number of objects?

The order of the objects inside their groups doesn't matter as well as the order of the groups itself doesn't matter.

Comment: What do you mean by "$g$ **identical** groups"? Must each group have the same  size? Or are you saying that two groups of the same size are not distinguishable? Edit: could you give an example with some small numbers?

Comment: Is this equivalent to finding the number of unique factors of $n$?

Comment: $$ \frac{n!}{g! (\frac{n}{g}!)^g}$$

Comment: For example: Assuming there are 4 values [1, 2, 3, 4] and they are distributed among 2 groups then the follwing distributions are considered equal: [[1, 2], [3, 4]] = [[2, 1], [3, 4]] = [[3, 4], [1, 2]].

These distributions are not considered equal: [[1, 2], [3, 4]] != [[1, 3], [2, 4]] != [[1, 4], [2, 3]].

Comment: The solution provided by karakfa appears to be correct, thank you very much.